# Reduce W to be between X and Y

Tags: javascript, vb.net, random, pseudocode

I will take an answer in any language... even pseudo-code... even just
an idea or a concept on how to do this.  (I'm working with VB.NET myself.)

I'll give you 3 values:

- W = 20141231
- X = 100
- Y = 200
- Z = ?

You have to mathematically reduce W... so that it will fall into the
range between X and Y (inclusively).  I'll call your result Z.

If you run that code over and over again... W will always be reduced to
the same value Z.

If I give you a new value tomorrow for W... it will also be reduced, but to a
different value for Z.  (I made W based on the current date, just to keep things
simple, and generate a different value for Z each day.)

Nothing can be random.

And no one will be able to predict what Z will be just by looking at W.
(Without stealing a copy of the code, of course.)  They won't even be able
to guess that Z will happen to be 190-200 more often than 100-110.  Instead, Z will
be approximately evenly distributed between 100-200 all the time.

What algorithm would you use?  You can't just reduce W to Y.  (That would be
predictable.)

You can't just pick a random number like 147.  (No random numbers allowed here.)

I tried things like repeatedly taking W and divide it by 2... until it was between X and Y.
(But I get far more 180-200 values for Z, than 100-120 values.... not "approximately evenly
distributed" as desired.)

No big discussions about "true random numbers" or "pseudo random" numbers.   Or exact definitions
of "evenly distributed" or "approximately evenly distributed".  A casual user would look
at a 1000 examples of Z and just feel it was "close enough" to be considered "approximately evenly distributed".

Comment: You are expected to provide at least an attempt at an answer. This question doesn't even provide an algorithm, much less any code.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to hashing algorithms.  The principle behind hashing (and pseudo-random number generators) usually involves taking the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) of a number to get a result evenly distributed between a range.

So for example, you could simply take `W % 101 + 100` to get a number between 100 and 200.  However, this would make `Z` very predictable because `W+1` would map to `Z+1`.  To make the mapping less obvious, you might first multiply by an arbitrary factor, say `37`.  This would give a result like:

```
W = 20141231
W * 37 = 745225547
W * 37 % 101 = 77
W * 37 % 101 + 100 = 177
```

One problem with using a small factor like `37` is that `W + 1` maps to `Z + 37`.  If someone who is trying to guess the link would simply compare a bunch of consecutive values of `W`, the pattern might be obvious.  So then you might use a confounding technique likely adding the sum of the digits in `W` (call it `D`) and then setting the multiplication factor to `(D + 37)`:

```
W = 20141231
D = 2+0+1+4+1+2+3+1=14
F = 37 + D = 51
W * 51 = 1027202781
W * 51 % 101 + 100 = 157
```

You can invent any sort of arbitrary logic to apply to `W` to make it appear more "random", then apply the modulus of 101 to get a number in the range 100-200.  Different techniques will result in more even or less even distribution, but you should be able to devise a technique that satisfies your requirements.